# StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ sometimes links to the wrong page

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

On StackOverflow, I dropped down the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™, and clicked on the highlighted link:

[image]

I should have wound up here:

[What popular "best practices" are not always best, and why?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14856/best-practices-that-you-disagree-with)

But instead I wound up here:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/14871/best-practices-that-you-disagree-with

Which displays "Page not found."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtle.

That second link is actually a pointer to an answer which had that comment.  It was deleted (thus the 404 you see), but the inbox reference to the *comment* on it wasn't.

This has been fixed in dev, and will go out with the next build.  Affected inbox items will remain, but no new ones exhibiting this behavior should be created.